# How to Turn on mobile data on all apps when each is set to off

Tags: mobile-data

I somehow  individually turned off mobile data on 250 apps. How do I turn all of them on. I don't remember how I did it. I am on a poco F1 android 9 miui 10.

Comment: Did you any app to switch mobile data off? Please update the question with your device models and Android version.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it through the settings but finally I found a popup view window titled restrict data that appeared when an app requested mobiledata permission, selected to restrict all and then clicked a second time to unrestrict all. It's an option at the top of the list of apps. It is different from the restrict data in the settings[image]